# Regex to remove punctuation where it isn't part of the word/value so leave %, £, ', but remove , ([ *

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, punctuation

I've read the wiki and the other suggested material, but I can't get my head around creating this Regex.

To detail it, it is required as I need to split a sentence into words, and only the word/values so I can compare each word to others in other sentences. This means cases where its "" is important to keep the dollar sign, as ten dollars is different to just 10, same for percentages and "Tom's" with apostrophes. With £$€#& only remove when not followed by a space as & can be used in company names such as B&Q, and money, the currency sign on its own is irrelevant to my needs.

So it would be: Remove all punctuation except £$€#&+- unless followed by a space, and remove % if a space precedes it.

Then I'll split by spaces into an array, its just this damn Regex.

I have a regex whitelist:

```
Regex.Replace(string, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+", "");
```

I just can't figure out how to specify a character+space or space+character such as to removes "$ " but leave $ when its "$10" I know \s is for which space but how to I attach to the regex I don't know.

Comment: Use string.split if you don't know how to use regex.

Comment: Well I want to remove not split initially, and having 1 regex expression will be better than the 10 or so separate string.removes I'll need. Also I'd rather not just settle for a messy approach because people don't want to help, its like this site isn't for asking question for help.....

Comment: If you cannot even provide us with example of how you tried to accomplish it on your own (at least that part removing `%` preceded by a space), we cannot believe you actually tried something before asking. If you are not willing to give your time to it, you can't expect us to do it either. It is not that hard to replace `/ %/` with empty string; or to find range of chars, then do `lookahead` for space and replace again. So go and try more please, provide us with what you have done and then we can actually help you :)

Comment: I have a basic regex white list for a-zA-Z-0-9 but thats all, I've edited my question to show this.

Answer (score 2):

@Tom, Of course you can use Regex, this is an answer to

> Well I want to remove not split initially, and having 1 regex expression will be better than the 10 or so separate string.removes I'll need. Also I'd rather not just settle for a messy approach because people don't want to help, its like this site isn't for asking question for help.....

and how it can be done with *String.Split* (I would post this as a comment if it would be shorter)

```
var symbols = "£$€#&%+-";
var punctuationsChars =  Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue)
                            .Select(i => (char)i)
                            .Where(c => char.IsPunctuation(c))
                            .Except(symbols)
                            .ToArray();

string input = "leave £10 remove £ and leave 10% remove % ok";

var parts = input.Split(punctuationsChars)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Split())
                 .Where(x => !(x.Length == 1 && symbols.Contains(x[0])))
                 .ToList();
```

So, you don't have to use regex If you don't know how to use it.

**Output: `leave £10 remove and leave 10% remove ok`**

Comment: I dunno how much I can say this, I need to remove symbols such as £, $ ONLY if its followed by a SPACE, example: "leave £10 remove £ and leave 10% remove % ok", should results in "leave £10 remove and leave 10% but remove ok" I don't think these conditions can be specified unless using regex or a mile long string.remove"£ ", "$", " &" etc.

Comment: @Tom `I need to remove symbols such as £, $ ONLY if its followed by a SPACE` Either you didn't test the code or you still understand what I mean. All you need is a simple *where* to filter when your char is the only char in the strings found.

Comment: Yep tested it, doesn't do what I've said, no where does it specify a condition of except if a space follows, all it does is list symbols to simply not remove.

Comment: @Tom I updated it with your simple requirement. Funny that you don't try to understand the codes posted but just want a turnkey solution. Are you a software developer or  a student just wanting to finish the homework as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex to do that:

```
var newStr = new string(originalStr.Where(c => !",([*\"".Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Ah nice, not seen this method before, how do I specify a space after a character? So to say remove "£ "

Comment: Add it to the characters that you want to remove in the `Where` clause: `var newStr = new string(originalStr.Where(c => !" ,([*\"".Contains(c)).ToArray());`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, adding a space after any character in that just removes all spaces from the string and not just where that character+ a space appears. Example sentence "This symbol £ should be removed but this one £10 shouldn't"

Comment: My fault - if you want to remove characters conditionally it would be better to use regex, but at least you have a starting option here

Comment: I have a regex white list of a-zA-Z0-9 its just figuring out how specify symbols+ space